# Picking an area on a grid

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

ok so i have a code that makes (n)lists in one list like for example

```
[[1,1,0,0],[0,1,1,0],[0,0,1,1],[1,0,0,1]]
```

Where it would print each as

```
[1 1 0 0]
[0 1 1 0]
[0 0 1 1]
[1 0 0 1]
```

Here is the code

```
import random
vertical=[]
horizontal=[]
size=int(input("Size? (even) "))
area=size**2
half=int(area//2)
thechosenhalf=random.sample(range(1, area), half) #generates numbers
# 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 (size = 4)
def printgrid():
    for b in range(size):
        print(f"{b}", end="")
        print("[" + " ".join([str(i) for i in vertical[b]])+ "]")
    print(f"  ", end="")
    for b in range(size):
        print(f"{b}", end=" ")
for j in range(size):
    for i in range(size):
        horizontal.append(0)
    vertical.append(horizontal)
    horizontal=[]
printgrid()
```

the code above me would print it like

```
0[0 0 0 0]
1[0 0 0 0]
2[0 0 0 0]
3[0 0 0 0]
  0 1 2 3
```

Im confused on how to make it so the generated numbers
where 1 = vertical[0][0] 2 = vertical[0][1]

So if thechosenhalf were numbers from 1 to 8 it would change
from

```
0[0 0 0 0]
1[0 0 0 0]
2[0 0 0 0]
3[0 0 0 0]
  0 1 2 3
```

to

```
0[1 1 1 1]
1[1 1 1 1]
2[0 0 0 0]
3[0 0 0 0]
  0 1 2 3
```

and if thechosenhalf were numbers 12 5 16 2 8 9 15 3 it would change
from

```
0[0 0 0 0]
1[0 0 0 0]
2[0 0 0 0]
3[0 0 0 0]
  0 1 2 3
```

to

```
0[0 1 1 0]
1[1 0 0 1]
2[1 0 0 1]
3[0 0 1 1]
  0 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are given an index `i` where `i=1` corresponds to the top left element of your grid, and subsequent indices move over rows. You want to output a `1` for all the indices you're given, and zero elsewhere. You could do this quite easily if you recognize that `(i - 1) // size` gives you the column index, and `(i - 1) % size` gives you the row index. So let's do that.

Note, in the interest of [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns), your `printgrid` function should only *print* the grid, and you should have a separate `makegrid` function to make the grid. Also, don't use global variables the way you have done. It's easy to write spaghetti code that's hard to debug since you don't know where each variable can be modified when you do this. Instead, pass relevant variables to each function. Also, I modified your function names to conform to [PEP 8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/), and your variable names so they describe what they do:

First, a function to create a grid of the given size, with the given `chosen_indices`:

```
def make_grid(size, chosen_indices):
    # Make a grid of zeros
    grid = [[0] * size for _ in range(size)]

    # Iterate over each index in chosen_indices, and set those elements to 1
    for i in chosen_indices:
        row, col = divmod(i - 1, size) # divmod does both the integer division and modulo operations and returns the results
        grid[row][col] = 1

    return grid
```

Then, a function to print any grid:

```
def print_grid(grid):
    if not grid:
        return
    
    size = len(grid[0])
    max_index_size = len(str(size-1))  # The size of the largest index that we'll have to print
    format_str = f"{{0: <{max_index_size}d}}" # Create a format string to output each element of the grid with the correct padding
    for row_index, row in enumerate(grid):
        print(format_str.format(row_index), end="[")
        for col_index, elem in enumerate(row):
            print(format_str.format(elem), end=" " * (col_index < size-1))
            # end=" " * (col_index < size-1) adds a space after elem except in the last column
      
        print("]")

    print(" " * max_index_size, end=" ")
    for col_index in range(size):
        print(format_str.format(col_index), end=" ")

    print()
```

Now, after you take the input `size` and create the random sample `thechosenhalf`, you can call these functions like so:

```
my_grid = make_grid(size, thechosenhalf)
print_grid(my_grid)
```

With your given inputs, we get the expected results:

```
my_grid = make_grid(4, range(1, 9))
print_grid(my_grid)
```

outputs:

```
0[1 1 1 1]
1[1 1 1 1]
2[0 0 0 0]
3[0 0 0 0]
  0 1 2 3
```

and

```
my_grid = make_grid(4, [12, 5, 16, 2, 8, 9, 15, 3])
print_grid(my_grid)
```

outputs:

```
0[0 1 1 0]
1[1 0 0 1]
2[1 0 0 1]
3[0 0 1 1]
  0 1 2 3
```

---

The shenanigans with the `max_index_size` and `format_str` inside `print_grid` were to allow larger grids to be printed nicely. For example:

```
my_grid = make_grid(15, range(1, 9))
print_grid(my_grid)
```

outputs:

```
0 [1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 ]
1 [0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 ]
2 [0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 ]
3 [0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 ]
4 [0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 ]
5 [0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 ]
6 [0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 ]
7 [0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 ]
8 [0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 ]
9 [0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 ]
10[0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 ]
11[0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 ]
12[0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 ]
13[0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 ]
14[0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 ]
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13 14
```

Removing those two lines and naively printing each element / index would have resulted in this broken output:

```
0[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
1[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
2[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
3[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
4[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
5[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
6[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
7[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
8[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
9[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
10[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
11[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
12[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
13[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
14[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14
```

Answer (score 0):

One idea may be to use a dictionary that assigns keys for each cell in the `2x2` grid, and iterate your `chosenhalf` list matching entries to the mapped cells in the grid:

```
grid = { 1:[0,0], 5:[1,0], 9:[2,0],  13:[3,0],
         2:[0,1], 6:[1,1], 10:[2,1], 14:[3,1],
         3:[0,2], 7:[1,2], 11:[2,2], 15:[3,2],
         4:[0,3], 8:[1,3], 12:[2,3], 16:[3,3],}


def printgrid():
    col = 1
    for cell in grid:
        if cell in chosenhalf:
            print(1, end=' ')
        else:
            print(0, end=' ')
        if col%4==0: print()
        col+=1


printgrid()

# Using your example: chosenhalf = [12, 5, 16, 2, 8, 9, 14, 15, 3]
# produces expected output:
0 1 1 0 
1 0 0 1 
1 0 0 1 
0 1 1 1
```

Of course, this is only a basic proof-of-concept and can be optimized for better performance, but may serve as a start to a possible solution.

Comment: This is so unnecessarily inefficient. You can easily get the row and column indices using `divmod`

Comment: What's the point of the dictionary in the first place? You never use any of the values in the dictionary